# What usage does 有 have in ~的有 (e.g. 偏向于data reseacher的有)

Tags: grammar

In [the following sentence over 知乎](https://www.zhihu.com/question/20935297/answer/28465543):

> 从我的观察来看，不同企业对于data scientist这个title的定义其实是有分歧的，**偏向于data reseacher的有**，多见于大型IT企业，百度大脑的data scientist们多属于这一类型，他们搞的是比较前沿的深度学习，平常会读大量paper可能自己也会发；**偏向于data creative的有**，各种企业都会储备，会ETL，懂模型、懂行业，会展示沟通，比较能够创造直接的价值。**偏向于data developer的也有**但是很少，他们不懂模型，只要给他们算法公式，他们就能用编程语言帮你实现，实现算法是重要的技能，但是这种不懂模型不懂行业的，现在大多企业都不太会给这样的人data scientist的title了。

The grammar book does not seem to have this usage of 有.

I feel that the meaning is similar to 关于 or 至于 (at least in this context), so the relevant sentence above can be rewritten as follows:

> 关于偏向于data researcher (or suffix "的话" here?)，
>
> 关于data developer，虽然他们比减少，

However, grammatically how does 有 work here? I just check out [the Chinese grammar wiki](https://resources.allsetlearning.com/chinese/grammar/%E6%9C%89) but didn't find any relevant pages.

Comment: 偏 inclined 向于 to data researcher/data creative 的 ones
有 there are， thus "there are those inclined to data researcher", " there are those inclined to data creative"
的 may refer to ＂data scientist这个title的定义＂mentioned before

Comment: verb 有 would usually precede its objects, data researcher/data creative 的 in the present case, but objects can be fronted

Comment: As a standalone phrase, `偏向于data reseacher的有` means exactly the same thing as `有偏向于data reseacher的` or `有的偏向于data reseacher` - if the latter two makes more sense to you. As mentioned in the comments above - it means "there are those [businesses] which prefer defining the term *data scientist* as a *data researcher*".

Answer (score 3):

I am a native speaker and consider myself a "data" person.

From my perspective, he didn't end the sentence properly and his array of sentences could be changed a bit like below so it's easier to understand.

> 从我的观察来看，不同企业对于data scientist这个title的定义其实是有分歧的。
>       **有**偏向于data reseacher**的**，多见于大型IT企业。百度大脑的data scientist们多属于这一类型，他们搞的是比较前沿的深度学习，平常会读大量paper可能自己也会发**文章**。

The purpose of **有...的** is to illustrate his/her point using example(s).

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't expect a strict grammar on the Internet, especially for social media. His meaning is clear, though his grammar is unpleasant. I feel uncomfortable with his sentences just as you do.